# Simple way to convert HH:MM:SS (hours:minutes:seconds.split seconds) to seconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

What's an easy way to convert `00:20:40.28` (HH:MM:SS) to seconds with a Bash script?

Split seconds can be cut out, it’s not essential.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try `awk`. As a bonus, you can keep the split seconds.

```
echo "00:20:40.25" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very clean way of doing it, just what I wanted.
As well maths isn’t really my strong point.

Comment: Quite useful, thanks! To decimal hours: `echo "00:20:40.25" | awk -F: '{ print $1 + ($2/60) + ($3/3600) }'`

Comment: @dreamlax, if i may, can you please explain the command in the part of the awk -f? also, is there any option to output the value as minutes and not as seconds?

Comment: And for [the opposite direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13422982/4970442), `date --utc --date @1240.25 +"%T"`

Answer (score 7):

This would work even if you don't specify hours or minutes: `echo "04:20:40" | sed -E 's/(.*):(.+):(.+)/\1*3600+\2*60+\3/;s/(.+):(.+)/\1*60+\2/' | bc`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
T='00:20:40.28'
SavedIFS="$IFS"
IFS=":."
Time=($T)
Seconds=$((${Time[0]}*3600 + ${Time[1]}*60 + ${Time[2]})).${Time[3]}
IFS="$SavedIFS"

echo $Seconds
```

($*<string>*) splits *<string>* based on the splitter (`IFS`).

${*<array>*[*<index>*]} returns the element of the *<array>*  at the *<index>*.

$((*<arithmetic expression>*)) performs the arithmetic expression.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `IFS=":."` and `Seconds=$(( ... ))${Time[3]}`

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "40.25" | awk -F: '{ if (NF == 1) {print $NF} else if (NF == 2) {print $1 * 60 + $2} else if (NF==3) {print $1 * 3600 + $2 * 60 + $3} }'
40.25
echo "10:40.25" | awk -F: '{ if (NF == 1) {print $NF} else if (NF == 2) {print $1 * 60 + $2} else if (NF==3) {print $1 * 3600 + $2 * 60 + $3} }'
640.25
echo "20:10:40.25" | awk -F: '{ if (NF == 1) {print $NF} else if (NF == 2) {print $1 * 60 + $2} else if (NF==3) {print $1 * 3600 + $2 * 60 + $3} }'
72640.25
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU date, you can perform the conversion if the duration is less than 24 hours, by treating it as a time of day on the epoch:

```
to_seconds() {
    local epoch=$(date --utc -d @0 +%F)
    date --utc -d "$epoch $1" +%s.%09N
}
```

Running it with the example from the question:

```
$ to_seconds 00:20:40.29
1240.290000000
```

Note that `--utc`, `@`, `%s` and `%N` are all GNU extensions not necessarily supported by other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are processing a time from `ps`, mind you that the format `2-18:01` is also possible for 2 days, 19 hours, 1 minute. In that case you'll want to checkout: [Parse ps' "etime" output and convert it into seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652445/parse-ps-etime-output-into-seconds)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert minutes to hour, seconds, or minutes with `bc` command.

By example:

How many minutes for 1000 sec ?

```
$ echo 'obase=60;1000' | bc
02 00
```

then -> 2 min

How much hour for 375 min ?

```
$ echo 'obase=60;375'| bc
06 15
```

then -> 06h15

How days for 56 hours?

```
$ echo 'obase=24;56' | bc
02 08
```

then 02 days and 08 hours

bc with obase is extra!

Comment: With bigger numbers to convert 14400 minutes in days ) :  `echo "obase=60;14777" | bc
 04 01 17  `  ( 4 days, 1 hours et 17 minutes  !)

Comment: 14400 minutes is 10 days (there are 24 hours in a day, not 60).

Comment: Effectively, I made a mistake. we don't do that. A convert in Hour is preferable... and take the minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what exactly do you have - SS, MM:SS or HH:MM:SS, like after `youtube-dl --get-duration`, then awk magic could be useful:

```
echo 12 | awk -F\: '{ for(k=NF;k>0;k--) sum+=($k*(60^(NF-k))); print sum }'
12
echo 35:12 | awk -F\: '{ for(k=NF;k>0;k--) sum+=($k*(60^(NF-k))); print sum }'
2112
echo 1:35:12 | awk -F\: '{ for(k=NF;k>0;k--) sum+=($k*(60^(NF-k))); print sum }'
5712
```

Comment: and works for this too:  `echo 1:35:12.3 | awk -F\: '{ for(k=NF;k>0;k--) sum+=($k*(60^(NF-k))); print sum }'` gave `5712.3`

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to count from the epoch time as:

```
$ date_var="00:20:40.28";
$ date +'%s.%3N' -d "1970-01-01 $date_var" --utc
1240.280
```

You can also easily change the format to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but, I think this is how you'd split the string.  Followed by multiplying by the appropriate amounts for hours and minutes.

```
mytime=’00:20:40.28′
part1=${mytime%%:*}; rest=${mytime#*:}
part2=${rest%%:*}; rest=${rest#*:}
part3=${rest%%:*};
```

Answer (score 0):

with the shell,

```
#!/bin/bash

d="00:20:40.28"
IFS=":"
set -- $d
hr=$(($1*3600))
min=$(($2*60))
sec=${3%.*}
echo "total secs: $((hr+min+sec))"
```

Comment: because of octal, fails for `09:08:40.28` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have this old shell function (/bin/sh compatible in the sense of POSIX shell, not bash) which does this conversion in integer math (no fractions in the seconds):

```
tim2sec() {
    mult=1
    arg="$1"
    res=0
    while [ ${#arg} -gt 0 ]; do
        prev="${arg%:*}"
        if [ "$prev" = "$arg" ]; then
            curr="${arg#0}"  # avoid interpreting as octal
            prev=""
        else
            curr="${arg##*:}"
            curr="${curr#0}"  # avoid interpreting as octal
        fi
        curr="${curr%%.*}"  # remove any fractional parts
        res=$((res+curr*mult))
        mult=$((mult*60))
        arg="$prev"
    done
    echo "$res"
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ tim2sec 1:23:45.243
5025
```

It works with SS, MM:SS and HH:MM:SS only :)

Answer (score 0):

```
TZ=utc date +'%s' -d "1970-01-01 00:00:38"
```