# Convert a time span in seconds to formatted time in shell

Tags: linux, shell, timespan, date-formatting

I have a variable of $i which is seconds in a shell script, and I am trying to convert it to 24 HOUR HH:MM:SS. Is this possible in shell?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Here's a fun hacky way to do exactly what you are looking for =)

```
date -u -d @${i} +"%T"
```

**Explanation:**

- The `date` utility allows you to specify a time, from string, in seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and output it in whatever format you specify.
- The `-u` option is to display UTC time, so it doesn't factor in timezone offsets (since start time from 1970 is in UTC)
- The following parts are GNU `date`-specific (Linux):

  - The `-d` part tells `date` to accept the time information from string instead of using `now`
  - The `@${i}` part is how you tell `date` that `$i` is in seconds
- The `+"%T"` is for formatting your output. From the `man date` page: `%T     time; same as %H:%M:%S`. Since we only care about the `HH:MM:SS` part, this fits!

Comment: Look at Alan Tam's answer below for how this works in a Mac/Unix : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21822510/243709

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning this only works for `i` lower than 86400s: `i=86400; date -u -d @${i} +"%T"` will give you `00:00:00`

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 I get `"invalid date «@»"` .

Comment: @TulainsCórdova then use `date -u -d @"$i" +"%T"`

Comment: Don't use the "u" switch if you want the times to be in your local time zone.

Comment: On macOS this should be `date -u -r "$i" +"%T"`

Comment: I'm trying this `$(date -d @${diff} '+%d days %T')`
This however returns '1 days 0:01:01' instead of '0 days 0:01:01' when diff=61

Comment: Why quote `"%T"` and not `"+%T"` or just no quotes, there's no shell substitution happening

Comment: to make it work for even more than 86400 seconds: `date -u +"$(( ${i} / 86400 ))d %T" -d "@${i}"`

Comment: @oneindelijk this is to be expected, because `date` does **not** display time spans but actual dates (technically it is counted from 1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00). and quoting from the man page: *"%d     day of month (e.g., 01)"* **-** so in your case date displays the 1970-01-01T00:01:01+00:00 but just the selected parts of it and `%-d` results in `1` because there is not a day 0 of a month. **||** for an even more hacky way to make it work for time spans >=1 day, have a look a my previous comment.

Answer (score 22):

Another approach: arithmetic

```
i=6789
((sec=i%60, i/=60, min=i%60, hrs=i/60))
timestamp=$(printf "%d:%02d:%02d" $hrs $min $sec)
echo $timestamp
```

produces `1:53:09`

Comment: may not have been what OP was after, but was exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

The `-d` argument applies to date from `coreutils` (Linux) only.

In BSD/OS X, use

```
date -u -r $i +%T
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$i` represents some date in second since the Epoch, you could display it with

```
  date -u -d @$i +%H:%M:%S
```

but you seems to suppose that `$i` is an interval (e.g. some duration) not a date, and then I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Same (duplicate) as @sampson-chen with the +%T.

Comment: And answered at the same time ;-) (to the minute, likely not to the second).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my algo/script helpers on my site:
http://ram.kossboss.com/seconds-to-split-time-convert/
I used this elogant algo from here: [Convert seconds to hours, minutes, seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199631/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds-in-bash)

```
convertsecs() {
 ((h=${1}/3600))
 ((m=(${1}%3600)/60))
 ((s=${1}%60))
 printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $h $m $s
}
TIME1="36"
TIME2="1036"
TIME3="91925"

echo $(convertsecs $TIME1)
echo $(convertsecs $TIME2)
echo $(convertsecs $TIME3)
```

Example of my second to day, hour, minute, second converter:

```
# convert seconds to day-hour:min:sec
convertsecs2dhms() {
 ((d=${1}/(60*60*24)))
 ((h=(${1}%(60*60*24))/(60*60)))
 ((m=(${1}%(60*60))/60))
 ((s=${1}%60))
 printf "%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $d $h $m $s
 # PRETTY OUTPUT: uncomment below printf and comment out above printf if you want prettier output
 # printf "%02dd %02dh %02dm %02ds\n" $d $h $m $s
}
# setting test variables: testing some constant variables & evaluated variables
TIME1="36"
TIME2="1036"
TIME3="91925"
# one way to output results
((TIME4=$TIME3*2)) # 183850
((TIME5=$TIME3*$TIME1)) # 3309300
((TIME6=100*86400+3*3600+40*60+31)) # 8653231 s = 100 days + 3 hours + 40 min + 31 sec
# outputting results: another way to show results (via echo & command substitution with         backticks)
echo $TIME1 - `convertsecs2dhms $TIME1`
echo $TIME2 - `convertsecs2dhms $TIME2`
echo $TIME3 - `convertsecs2dhms $TIME3`
echo $TIME4 - `convertsecs2dhms $TIME4`
echo $TIME5 - `convertsecs2dhms $TIME5`
echo $TIME6 - `convertsecs2dhms $TIME6`

# OUTPUT WOULD BE LIKE THIS (If none pretty printf used): 
# 36 - 00-00:00:36
# 1036 - 00-00:17:16
# 91925 - 01-01:32:05
# 183850 - 02-03:04:10
# 3309300 - 38-07:15:00
# 8653231 - 100-03:40:31
# OUTPUT WOULD BE LIKE THIS (If pretty printf used): 
# 36 - 00d 00h 00m 36s
# 1036 - 00d 00h 17m 16s
# 91925 - 01d 01h 32m 05s
# 183850 - 02d 03h 04m 10s
# 3309300 - 38d 07h 15m 00s
# 1000000000 - 11574d 01h 46m 40s
```

Answer (score 0):

I use C shell, like this:

```
#! /bin/csh -f

set begDate_r = `date +%s`
set endDate_r = `date +%s`

set secs = `echo "$endDate_r - $begDate_r" | bc`
set h = `echo $secs/3600 | bc`
set m = `echo "$secs/60 - 60*$h" | bc`
set s = `echo $secs%60 | bc`

echo "Formatted Time: $h HOUR(s) - $m MIN(s) - $s SEC(s)"
```