# Time elapsed since variable

Tags: bash

I need time elapsed since `$var`

```
$var= [19:11:27 19:34:09]
```

`$var` was created from

```
date "+[%y:%m:%d %T]"
```

Comment: Which units for the elapsed time? (secs, days, etc)

Comment: days, hours, and mins. @sergio

Comment: searching here for `[bash] time elapsed` shows 240+ Q/A. Did you look at any of them? Good luck.

Comment: To get elapsed seconds: `elapsed=$(($(date +'%s')-$(date -d '19-11-27 19:34:09' +'%s')))`. To change seconds to day-hour-minute see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27820847/5411198

Comment: @sergio how do i change `date -d '19-11-27 19:34:09' to `date -d'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083053/date-utils-date-difference-piping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083053/date-utils-date-difference-piping/59083202#59083202 I answered my own question and this is the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

If `mktime` function of `awk` is available, how about:

```
awk -v var='[19:11:28 14:34:09]' '
BEGIN {
    split(var, a, "[^0-9]")
    elapsed = systime() - mktime(a[2]+2000" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6]" "a[7])
    d = int(elapsed / 86400)
    h = int((elapsed - d * 86400) / 3600)
    m = int((elapsed - d * 86400 - h * 3600) / 60) 
    printf("%d days %d hours %d mins passed.\n", d, h, m)
}'
```

Comment: How do i use this... i put it in a script..and errors... i see this looks like unix... idk how to use it. Also seems unnecessary... d= h= and m=.

Comment: Please copy the code above and save as a file e.g. `file.awk`, then execute `bash file.awk` on the command line. If you still have an error, please let me know including the error message. BR.

Answer (score 0):

Few alternative,

**If you can change the setting of `var`:**

You are better using the `SECONDS` bash variable. You can then use bash math to calculate difference, and format the output.

```
 # Instead of var=...
START=$SECONDS
... do something that take long time
... to executed
FINISH=$SECONDS
ELAPSED=$((FINISH-START))
```

**If you can NOT change the setting of `var`:**

You will have to convert var to a format that date will accept, and use the methods suggested in the comments. Minimal effort to convert to ISO YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
VX=20${var/:/-}   # Replace first : with -, add 2000 to the yy part
VX=${var/:/-}     # Replace Second : with -
START=$(date -d "$VX" +'%s')
FINISH=(date +'%s')
ELAPSED=$((FINISH-START))
```

Comment: @HugoSlop The most difficult thing about your question is how to parse the date format you have (`[%y:%m:%d %T]`) into something more useful. If it's possible to *start* with a simpler representation -- like the number of seconds since the shell started (`$SECONDS`), the task gets much easier. Seconds since the unix epoch (`date +%s`) would also work well.

Comment: @HugoSlop I've fixed the formatting, and added logic for case that the value of 'var' can not be modified.