# Date utils date difference piping

Tags: bash

I am using date utils to try and calculate elapsed time. For example `$var = 19-11-27 22:36:47` Which is created by
`date "+%y-%m-%d %T"`
This was made awhile back.
I need to turn it into another variable. So I would think this would work.

```
foo=$(dateutils.ddiff | echo "$var" | date "+%y-%m-%d %T" | -f '%dD %HH %mM')
```

running this i get

```
./script.sh: line 7: -f: command not found
ddiff: Error: reference DATE must be specified
```

So how do I pipe this correctly or is their an alternative?

Comment: You are running a program called `-f`, but you don't have a program of this name. What is the command `-f '%dD %HH %mM'` supposed to do? Also, `date` does not read from stdin, so it doesn't make sense to pipe something into `date`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$Value1=19-11-27 22:36:47
$Value2=date "+%y-%m-%d %T" 
var=$(date -u -d @$(($(date -d "$Value2" '+%s') - $(date -d "$Value1" '+%s'))) '+%H:%M')
```

I ditched date utils for this.

Comment: The lines you have posted don't make sense in bash. Did you ever copy&paste them into a bash command line, to see what they are doing?