# Is there a unix program to convert various HH:MM:SS formats to seconds?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a flat file with data in the following format

```
(1+01:01)
(06:18)
(00:02)
```

I can use awk to sum up the data if it's in the form of seconds like so

```
16
32
64

cat file | awk '{SUM+=$1} END {print SUM}'
```

Is there a way I can convert the values stored in the flat file to seconds?

Comment: Can you give a sample `date` command to convert `1+01:01` to seconds?

Comment: `gawk` has [date/time functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) which may be of interest to you. If you just want to calculate seconds, why don't you just multiply it out. Exactly what is your expected output? What is `1+01:01`?

Comment: I can multiply it out, I was just wondering if there were any built in tools to do it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU date is pretty good at parsing dates, but `1+01:01` is not supported. You could still use it if you let sed modify the input a little bit, and assuming it means `1 hour + 1 hour + 1 minute`.

Here's is one way you could parse the file with GNU grep, sed and date:

```
<infile grep -o '[^()]*' | 
sed 's/^([0-9]+)[+-]/\1 hour /; 
     s/^/date -d "/; 
     s/$/ 1970-01-01 UTC" +%s/e'
```

Output:

```
7260
22680
120
```

Leave of the `e` flag to see what commands sed is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `awk` for this as well? Check out this stackoverflow answer: [Simple way to convert HH:MM:SS (hours:minutes:seconds.split seconds) to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181712/simple-way-to-convert-002040-28-hoursminutesseconds-split-seconds-to-secon)

Comment: @Steve That would be impossible because Max has 1 rep.